# MySQL fails to update a TIMESTAMP field with '2014-10-19 00:00:00'

Tags: mysql

I have a `TIMESTAMP` field and it is not accepting the value `2014-10-19 00:00:00`.

I am using MySQL 5.6 and I have tested both in Windows and Linux versions.

What should I write if the first format is not accepted ?

Comment: can you please post a structure of the table and the query, or if you have any restricts? As updating table with this datetime, works fine

Comment: Also, show your exact `update` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table thing9
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    theWhat varchar(80) not null,
    theWhen timestamp not null
);
insert thing9(theWhat,theWhen) values('fish','2014-10-19 00:00:00');
insert thing9(theWhat,theWhen) values('fish','2012-10-19 00:00:00');
insert thing9(theWhat,theWhen) values('fish','2016-10-19 00:00:00');

update thing9 set theWhen='2011-10-19 00:00:00' where id=2;

+----+---------+---------------------+
| id | theWhat | theWhen             |
+----+---------+---------------------+
|  1 | fish    | 2014-10-19 00:00:00 |
|  2 | fish    | 2011-10-19 00:00:00 |
|  3 | fish    | 2016-10-19 00:00:00 |
+----+---------+---------------------+

mysql> show variables like '%versi%';
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.24                       |
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| version                 | 5.6.24-log                   |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | Win64                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
```

### Edit:

I wonder if you have issues with mysql timezones. Please check out the Mysql Manual Page link [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html), and below is a small extract from it.

> mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone; timezone values
>   can be given in several formats, none of which are case sensitive:
>
> The value 'SYSTEM' indicates that the time zone should be the same as
>   the system time zone.
>
> The value can be given as a string indicating an offset from UTC, such
>   as '+10:00' or '-6:00'.

### Edit2:

```
show variables where variable_name like '%datetime%'
+-----------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name   | Value             |
+-----------------+-------------------+
| datetime_format | %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s |
+-----------------+-------------------+
```

If you are in D-M-Y order or something else, then change according.

Comment: I think there is something related to the version of the server. I tried exactely the same script above and I got two different results:

v5.1.56 = I got an error inserting "2014-10-19 00:00:00"

v5.6.21 = When I inserted "2014-10-19 00:00:00" it actually inserted "2014-10-19 **01**:00:00".

Comment: Drew, I checked it out and both systems (Win and Linux) gave me the same result: "SYSTEM, SYSTEM"

Comment: Hey Drew, the datetime_format variable equals "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s" in both systems (Win & Linux).

Comment: not sure what yourfull output is. I showed you mine. Shown same on your systems

Comment: Drew,
I am sorry but I don't know how to format the result properly. 
But I can tell you that the result was exactely the same of yours.

Comment: i don;t know how more to help. I hope someone else comes along to help

Comment: Drew, first of all thank you a lot for helping me with this issue.

My current report is:

I just installed a brand-new Virtual Machine with Win7 and MySQL 5.6.26 and I got the same error: 

**Incorrect datetime value: '2014-10-19 00:00:00' for column 'theWhen'**

Do you have any idea?